Command line Archiving utility for Windows
I currently use an archive utility in the command line to create an archive zip file.
I need to have a specific folder structure within the archive file so when it's extracted all data is in the correct structure.
Currently to get the correct structure I use robocopy to copy all data from different locations into my preferred folder structure and once that is done I use the archive utility to create the archive.
The size of the data is getting quite large now so I'd like to skip the robo copy part and add the data directly into the archive.
Does anyone know of a command line based archive utility that allows you to specify a folder within the archive
For example the copy from location could be c:\folder1\folder2\folder3*.* and c:\somewhereelse\folder2\folder3*.* I want this to go into a single folder within the zip file called 'contents'
This way when the archive is extracted all the files extract to a folder called 'contents' relative to wherever it gets extracted.
PS - needs to run Windows CMD

7z doesn't allow that directly, but it allows renaming files inside the archive, this could be a possible workaround. See this answer.
7z rn <archive_name> <src_file_1> <dest_file_1> [ <src_file_2> <dest_file_2> ... ]

